# Help on Facebook Graph API, returns "false" but UID is public

Tags: facebook, graph, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I really could not understand why on some Facebook objects (being more specific: user posts) the Graph API returns false when using an access_token obtained via OAuth by an application, but NOT by using a user access_token.

I have an example here:
https://graph.facebook.com/10150158049595775?access_token=XXXXXXXXXX

This post is public, and I have no friends in common with this user.

If you try to access the url above by using a token obtained via the usual Facebook OAuth scheme, the server return "false".

If you use your user access token, for example the one that FB gives you by visiting the examples in this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, the Graph API correctly gives you the users's post detail.

I believe it's not a matter of extended permissions required, first because the post above is public, and second, because for testing I've tried to make my application generate a token by asking ALL user permissions (yes, all permissions found on developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) and the answer was always "false".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *suppose* this post is "*Available to everyone on Facebook*", which *may* be the reason why Facebook is accepting a user `access_token` (i.e. viewing the post as a user) and not accepting an application `access_token`.

Also note that this would work without `access_token` (if you prepend the owner id):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/752020774_10150158049595775
```

I ***guess*** this is treated as "*Publicly accessible*"

Comment: By using notation "ownerid_postid" that you suggested the Graph Api no more answers "false", even when using the token granted to my application. So this completely solved my problem, thank you very much.